# SQL DATEDIFF Function returns wrong values

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Im executing following sql statement to get the sum values using date difference as a condition. "t_QueryDemand" is the table name and "DESIRED_SHIP_DATE" is the value I compare with current system date. But, I always get a date difference higher than 44100, even though the actual difference is between 0-60. DESIRED_SHIP_DATE data type is datetime2(7). I'm using MS SQL server database. What could be the issue.

```
Dim curDate As Date = Date.Today()

Dim strSql7DayDemand As date= "SELECT SUM(ORDER_QTY) AS ORDQTY, (TOTAL_SHIPPED_QTY) AS SHIPQTY, DATEDIFF(day," & curDate & ",DESIRED_SHIP_DATE),DESIRED_SHIP_DATE as DIFF from t_QueryDemand where ID='" & Trim(txtPartID.Text) & "' AND DATEDIFF(DAY," & curDate & ",DESIRED_SHIP_DATE) >" &
```

[image]

Comment: Learn to use parameters!

Comment: I don't doubt for a second that if you passed a Date and Time datatype parameter, instead of **insecurely** injecting `curDate` (and `txtPartID.Text`) this would work correctly.

Comment: Will parameters solve the issue?

Comment: Very likely, along with that *huge* security vulnerability you have, @lakshithadilhan . *In fact after a second look I can say, with **certainty**, it will.*

Comment: i'll try. Thanks

Comment: Make an effort and learn to post smart questions. Don't post important information as images. Your image has no column headers, putting the burden on your reader to decipher it. Don't post fragments of code. Learn to debug dynamic tsql - that requires that you SEE the code you are writing (and post it as well). And learn to write code that accurately reflects what is does. Here you have a variable named "date". Is that what it really contains?

Comment: Ok. ill post the whole code next time. I don't have a variable called date. Its curDate and will hold the current system date by using  "Date.Today()"

Comment: `Dim strSql7DayDemand As date=` As Date? Sure looks like a string to me. Also what is the trailing & at the end of the Select?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a injection use the SQL function GETDATE()

```
DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),DESIRED_SHIP_DATE)
```

This will calculate the date on the server instead of locally like you are currently doing.

As has been pointed out you have a serious security vulnerability -- you need to use parameterized queries and not string concatenation or you are vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.

It will also make your code more robust -- right now you have txtPartID.Text and you are just putting that into your query but what if someone enters an non-number in this field -- you have no way of catching that now.  With a parameterized query of a numeric type you would catch this problem when you converted the data entry to a number.

Comment: That won't solve the other injection issue: `"...ID='" & Trim(txtPartID.Text) & "'..."` Parametrising the the only true correct answer here.

Comment: @Larnu -- there you go -- I addressed your issue.  Probably will never be read by the OP.

Comment: @lakshithadilhan -- on stack overflow we trade in up votes.  If an answer what helpful you should vote it up -- if it answered your questions you show mark it as answered by clicking on the checkmark.  Nothing wrong with both :)   Godd luck